# CNAME subdomain.siteA.com to subdomain.siteB.com (on shared server) not working

Tags: apache, dns, cname, whm, a-records

Ok, i've seen this question posted elsewhere but can't seem to find the correct answer.  So like the title says, i've tried to set up a CName entry:

subdomain.siteA.com go to subdomain.siteB.com

It works somewhat.  When i ping subdomain.siteA.com, i get the same ipaddress as subdomain.siteB.com.  So thats working as expected.

The problem is when you enter the url subdomain.siteA.com in the browser it goes seems to go to the ipaddress, but because its a shared server and there are multiple domains, it doesn't show the correct website.  It shows internal error instead.  I believe this is because the IP is a shared IP.

So like if i use the ipaddress i could navigate to the correct website by entering something like this:  https://192.163.214.xxx/~username/SiteFolder/ 
or this would work too:
https://subdomain.siteA.com/~username/SiteFolder/

So i'm definitely pointing to the correct server/ip right?

So my question is, how can i make it go to correct site since its a shared ipaddress?  is it some sort of dns record i need to add on site b, or a file i need to modify on server, or something i can do whm or cpanel? Or is it just not possible?  I feel like there's got to be a way. I have a dedicated server just fyi.

Thank you all ahead of time.  I'm no expert for sure, so i truly appreciate everyone's advice.

Comment: Is this a cpanel server?  You tagged WHM in your tags.

Comment: I have whm root access and each site has a cpanel.

Comment: Shared IP's aren't a problem for cPanel.  On one of my WHM/cPanel servers, I have almost 100 sites with shared IPs, including sub-domains and such.  I'd start checking settings here Home »Server Configuration »Tweak Settings and then domains tab. You may also eventually want to go here Home »Security Center »Apache mod_userdir Tweak and disable the tilde.

Answer (score 0):

As you have added a cNAME record "subdomain.siteB.com" for the site "subdomain.siteA.com", it will redirect the requests for the site subdomain.siteA.com to to the site subdomain.siteB.com. In your case,please check if the site http://subdomain.siteB.com is accessible and working properly.